# What CSS frameworks have you found useful?

Tags: css, css-frameworks

My extreme frustration with CSS is its inability to work nicely across different browsers (and different versions of browsers--yes, I'm talking about you IE).

What CSS frameworks have people come across and what are some of their specific benefits? I heard today about the Object Oriented CSS framework, but I haven't yet had time to look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [blueprintcss.org](http://www.blueprintcss.org/img/blueprint_header_clean.png))</sub>

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

Rapid Blueprint CSS Layout With Boks

http://designshack.co.uk/articles/css/rapid-blueprint-css-layout-with-boks

> Blueprint is a CSS framework, which
>   aims to cut down on your development
>   time. It gives you a solid foundation
>   to build your project on top of, with
>   an easy-to-use grid, sensible
>   typography, useful plugins, and even a
>   stylesheet for printing.

What does Blueprint have to offer?

```
* A CSS reset that eliminates the discrepancies across browsers.
* A solid grid that can support the most complex of layouts.
* Typography based on expert principles that predate the web.
* Form styles for great looking user interfaces.
* Print styles for making any webpage ready for paper.
* Plugins for buttons, tabs and sprites.
* Tools, editors, and templates for every step in your workflow.
```

Comment: What kind of overhead does it have?